# Scraped data is not getting displayed on the webpage

Tags: python, html, django, web-scraping, web-development-server

I am working with Beautiful Soup for web scraping. I want to display the data on the webpage but the code doesn't works.
This is my views.py:

```
def index(request):
    session=request.Session() 
    session.headers={"User-Agent":"Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"}
    url="https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/9d531fc505eb4a93a90a7e8303ccaa22a142c9370b68391129de5019ee7adf5b"
    content=session.get(url,verify=False).content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
    for hit in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'today_nowcard-temp'}):
        head=hit.text
        summ=(hit.next_sibling.text)
        weather=News()
        weather.head=head
        weather.summ=summ
        weather.save()
    return redirect("../")

def news_list(request):
    weathers=News.objects.all()
    context={
        'object_list': weathers,
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

This is my index.html where I want the data to be displayed:

```
<div class="trending-top mb-30">
                            <div class="trend-top-img">
                                <div class="trend-top-cap">
                                    <span>{{head}}</span>
                                    <h2><a href="details.html">{{summ}}</a></h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Below is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
class News(models.Model):
    head=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summ=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you get with `BeautifulSoup` and if you really save it. Maybe you never get data.

Comment: you send `object_list` to template but you don't use it in template so what do you expect ? You need at least `{% for item in object_list %}{{ item.head }}{{ item.summ }}{% endfor }}`

Comment: Thanks but I think so my code isn't working the data is still not getting displayed

Comment: first check what you have in `weathers` before you send to template - maybe it is empty. Use at least `print(weathers)` . You could also check if `BeautifulSoup` gets any information - maybe server blocks you and you don't get any information. You can also use any database editor/viewer (like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)) to check if you have any data in database.

Comment: I have postgres database..... actually the data is not getting updated I think so dat is not getting scrapped successfully

Comment: so use `print()` to see if code is executed - maybe you never run function which add data to database, or it can't get data but it gets HTML with some useful information - save HTML to file and open in web browser. You may also visit Weather.com API to get data legally [doc](https://weather.com/swagger-docs/call-for-code), [register](https://callforcode.weather.com/register/). I use other API from different portal - [OpenWeatherMap](https://openweathermap.org/api) because they have some data for free.

Comment: print() statement is also not working as no output is shown in the terminal giving rise to whole set of new errors ,I have asked in another post. I think my code needs a little updation.

Comment: if `print()` doesn't display text then code is never executed - and this is your problem. Probably you never execute `index()` - maybe you have wrong routes in `urls.py`